# How do match properties from two Firebase collections?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Firebase-React project, I've created two collections: 'users' to hold registered user details, and 'gig-listings' to hold the gig information that registered users post to Firebase.
The user document looks like this:

```
email: ''
userId:''
venueAddress:''
venueName:''
```

...and the 'gig-listing' document is as follows:

```
date:'',
genre:'',
name:'',
price:'',
tickets:'',
time:'',
venueName:''
```

In my react component `UniqueVenueListing`, I'm trying to return a list of the gigs only submitted by the current signed in user (the user in this case is a gig venue, and the purpose of this component is to display **only** the gigs specific for that venue).

In my initial attempt, I tried to match the `venueName` from the gig listing with the `venueName` property of the current logged-in user - which didn't work, as `auth().currentUser.venueName` returned undefined:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { auth } from 'firebase/app'

const UniqueVenueListing = () => {

const [gigs, setGigs] = useState([])
const user = auth().currentUser

axios
.get("https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings")
.then(res => {
    const filteredGigs = res.data
    .filter(gig => {
        gig.venueName = user.venueName
    })
    setGigs({
        gigs:filteredGigs
    })
})

    return(
        <div>
            {
                gigs.map(gig => {
                    return gig
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default UniqueVenueListing
```

So - what properties in 'user' and 'gig-listing' can I match to return a filtered list of gigs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `auth().currentUser` call returns a Firebase Authentication user object, which knows nothing of the custom data that you store for that user in Cloud Firestore (such as their `venueName`).

If you want to use the `venueName` in your filtering code, you'll need to first load the user document from your database, and look up its value.